# Get odesk access token using OAuth1.0

Tags: java, javascript, php

I have to get access token of odesk.I am using OAuth1.0 but i could not get it.Please any one help me to solve such issue.

Following procedure i am using:

http://developers.odesk.com/w/page/38106543/Authentication-using-OAuth

callback url and Oauth Varifier these two step was successfully.

But when I go in third step for get permanent access token it show following error:

```
web page not access
```

I also use postman tool for generate access token, but in this I am getting:

```
Base url not proper..
```

Please some one help me.